# Surface energy in a solid cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, surface-tension

I have been trying this for over an hour and I still can't proceed:

$$F = 2 \pi RT$$
$$W = F(\text{displacement})$$
$$W = 2 \pi R (\text{displacement})$$
$$W = 2 \pi R \Delta x \ \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \ W = 2 \pi R dx $$

I couldn't do beyond this as I am struggling to think about the limits,
should they be the height of the cylinder or the circumference?

I also wanted to know if I could use the standard formula for a 2D cylinder in this case $W = T \Delta x$

Comment: T is the surface tension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force per unit length $f$, and tension $T(r)$ force per unit area:

$$
  F_{total} = f \times L = 2\pi r L T(r).
$$

And push the radius from $r$ to $r+dr$, the amount of work done:

$$
   dW = F_{total} \times dr = f(r) L dr = 2\pi r dr L T(r). 
$$

The work per unit length $w = W / L$:

$$
  dw = f(r) dr = 2 T(r) \pi r dr.
$$

Therefore, work per unit length from $r_1 \to r_2$ is :

$$
  w = \int dw = 2 \pi \int_{r_1}^{r_2} T(r) r dr. 
$$